# How to make letter replace after it has been added?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a working script to replace non alphanumerical letters from the text input. If you add  special chars to text input, it doesnt let you to add to there. However, I want this script delete the special char after you add the letter, means that you can see the letter there but just after that it hs been removed (like when you try to upvote your own question on stackoverflow)

```
$("#nick").on("keypress", function(event) {


    var englishAlphabetAndWhiteSpace = /[A-Za-z]/g;

    var key = String.fromCharCode(event.which);

    if (event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39 || englishAlphabetAndWhiteSpace.test(key)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
});
```

What is the correct way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to show the letter and then remove it, use 'keyup' event

```
$('#test').on('keyup keypress', function(e) {
    var reg = /[A-Za-z]/;
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value && !reg.test(value[value.length - 1])) {
        $(this).val(value.slice(0, value.length - 1));
    }
})
```

[Code on jsfiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/pogd9ot2/2/)

Comment: Clearest answer, but if you press the unallowed key for a long time, it doesnt remove. Oups...

Comment: @user198989 You are right, just add keypress to it, `'keyup kepress'`   I have already change the answer

Comment: Yes, this way, it doesnt let you to add flooded same letter if you press it longer, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex that'll replace all the non-alphabetic characters in the input value.

1. Use HTML5 `pattern` attribute on `input` to give regex
2. Use `keyup` and `input` event handlers to capture events
3. Use negated class regex to remove all non-alphabet symbols
4. Use `setTimeout` to clear the special characters after a delay

```js
var timeout;
$("#nick").on("keypress input", function(e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; // Browser-independant

  // If left or right arrow, then don't do anything
  if (keyCode === 8 || keyCode === 37 || keyCode === 39) {
    return true;
  }

  var $this = $(this); // Cache this
  clearTimeout(timeout); // Clear previous timeouts

  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    $this.val($this.val().replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g, ''));
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
input:valid {
  color: green;
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="nick" pattern="[A-Za-z]+" />
```

**Regex Explanation:**

The regex on `pattern`, `[A-Za-z]+` only matches one or more of the alphabet characters both uppercase and lowercase.

Comment: Thanks but when I add + for example, it just doesnt show up even.

Comment: @user198989 Do you want to allow `+` symbol?

Comment: No, I mean, my question is, if you add a non allowed char, it should be seems there and righafter be deleted. How to do that ? Because my script already does what yours does.

Answer (score 1):

If I read it correctly, you are talking about inserting a delay before the invalid character vanishes?

It's a bit trickier as there is the clause of how long you want to see it before it vanishes & also what if you are faster than typing the next letter before it does.

After taking care of these, it should look something like this :

```js
var removelast = false, remover;

var nick = $("#nick").on("keypress", function(event) {

    function remove() {
        nick.val(nick.val().slice(0,-1));
        removelast = false;
    }
  
    clearTimeout(remover);
    if(removelast) remove();
   
    var englishAlphabetAndWhiteSpace = /[A-Za-z]/g;

    var key = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
    var allowed = event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39 || englishAlphabetAndWhiteSpace.test(key);
    if (!allowed) {
        removelast = true;
        remover = setTimeout(remove, 100);
    }

    return true;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="nick" >
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It works if you press the unallowed key once, but if you press the unallowed key for a long time, it doesnt remove. Oups...

Comment: Yea..Corrected the logic